# Can a CRC32 engine be used for computing CRC16 hashes?

Tags: hash, crc, crc32, adler32

I'm working with a microcontroller with native HW functions to calculate CRC32 hashes from chunks of memory, where the polynomial can be freely defined. It turns out that the system has different data-links with different bit-lengths for CRC, like 16 and 8 bit, and I intend to use the hardware engine for it.

In simple tests with [online tools](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) I've concluded that it is possible to find a 32-bit polynomial that has the same result of a 8-bit CRC, example:

- hashing "a sample string" with 8-bit engine and poly 0xb7 yelds a result 0x97
- hashing "a sample string" with 16-bit engine and poly 0xb700 yelds a result 0x9700
- ...32-bit engine and poly 0xb7000000 yelds a result 0x97000000
  (with zero initial value and zero final xor, no reflections)

So, padding the poly with zeros and right-shifting the results seems to work.
But is it 'always' possible to find a set of parameters that make 32-bit engines to work as 16 or 8 bit ones? (including poly, final xor, init val and inversions)

To provide more context and prevent 'bypass answers' like 'dont't use the native engine': I have a scenario in a safety critical system where it's necessary to prevent a common design error from propagating to redundant processing nodes. One solution for that is having software-based CRC calculation in one node, and hardware-based in its pair.

Comment: The answer from @mark-adler in the question [using part of crc32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194839/using-only-part-of-crc32) made me uncertain about my initial conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing will work in general for CRCs that are not reflected. The pre and post conditioning can be done very simply with code around the hardware instructions loop.

Assuming that the hardware CRC doesn't have an option for this, to do a reflected CRC you would need to reflect each input byte, and then reflect the final result. That may defeat the purpose of using a hardware CRC. (Though if your purpose is just to have a different implementation, then maybe it wouldn't.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to guess.  You can calculate it.  Because CRC is a remainder of a division by an irreducible polynomial, it's a 1-to-1 function on its domain.

So, CRC16, for example, has to produce 65536 (64k) unique results if you run it over 0 through 65536.

To see if you get the same outcome by taking parts of CRC32, run it over 0 through 65535, keep the 2 bytes that you want to keep, and then see if there is any collision.

If your data has 32 bits in it, then it should not be an issue.  The issue arises if you have less than 32 bit numbers and you shuffle them around in a 32-bit space.  Their 1st and last byte are not guaranteed to be uniformly distributed.